# Is there a way to access a SKPhysicsBody's path?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game I create a very large physicsbody from an image by using **SKPhysicsBody(... alphaThreshold:...)**
This works fine, but since the image and physicsbody is quite large, it can take around 5 - 7 seconds to load.

My question is - is there a way I can access the physicsbody's path once it has been created through alphaThreshold and ***then*** - perhaps - copy the path's coordinates and use **SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)** since it doesn't have to generate a physicsbody from an image every single time?

**Edit:** Or would using an external program to determine the physics path be a better option?

Thanks!

Comment: No,  I have asked this question before,  it is impossible.  I recommend using PhysicsEditor https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Comment: BTW, if your physics body takes 5~7 seconds to load, then I would look at reducing your physics body or your image size.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into that. Cheers.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon quick question, how should I export my physicsbody from PhysicsEditor? Cheers.